# Has the person in the suit ever also supplied the sounds for the creature/character they portray?

Tags: history-of, behind-the-scenes, actors

Every once in a while, I come across someone who [thought Peter Mayhew did the wookiee sounds for Chewbacca](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133847/54827), or something like that, when in actuality [those sounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iEm7gW2I38) were [create by](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUwnFYBPMlU) sound designer Ben Burt in post-production. As a kid, I even thought the actors in the Jawa cloaks were the ones making those Jawa sounds! All this got me thinking, **has there ever been a case of the person in the suit also supplying the sounds for the creature/character they portray?**

IMPORTANT NOTE: I'm asking about creatures/characters who *don't have a lot of (english) lines*, like Chewie. We're talking grunting, roaring, hissing, or strange, exotic languages like wookiee roars, so Jar Jar, Dobby, C-3PO, Yoda, and Unkar Plutt *don't count* **since they speak "english" a lot**. I'd say *if they have **more than 10 to 15 lines** of normal (english) dialogue, then they probably are **not** what I'm looking for.* Also notice that by "inside the suit" I'm including CGI motion capture characters.

---

- Example answer 1: The puppeteer who worked Jabba's mouth also spoke the huttese lines on set (and maybe later re-recorded the lines in post-production) [Disclaimer: I made that up!]
- Example answer 2: The guy in the motion capture suit who provided the movements for Sebulba spoke the huttese lines (and maybe later re-recorded the lines in post-production) [Disclaimer: I made that up too!]
- Example answer 3: The guy in the motion capture suit who provided the movements for King Kong also recorded Kong's many grunts and breathing etc. in post-production. [Disclaimer: I made that up, I have no idea if that's true!]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FD9rlb1QAqM

Comment: I wouldn't put it past the Spaceballs "Dink Dink" song to be the same actors who are seen in the little brown robes. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: @Mazura I'd say if they have more than 10 to 15 lines of normal (english) dialogue, then they probably aren't what I'm looking for. (I heard that Caesar the ape only has 1 line of english, so he would count. I may even count Groot since he only says the same three words and then mosly grumbles and huffs. The Na'vi from Avatar are borderline, as _some_ spoke a lot of english, but then others never spoke english.)

Comment: This seems pretty broad. Presumably there are **hundreds** of films where the person in the suit also provided the sounds, especially in older/cheaper B-Movies.

Comment: I think this happens a lot nowadays - I believe Benedict Cumberbatch provided the mocap for his portrayal of Smaug, and also 90% of the cast of Avatar seems to fall under this.

Comment: With Foley being what it is, I doubt even actors playing humans do any of their own non-dialog sounds. Burps, coughs, sneezes - what have you - are all typically dubbed in later for all but the most low-budget productions.  Roars, honks, gurgles, etc. of non-human characters are likely no exception.

Comment: Incidentally, your assumption about King Kong is true, I believe: Andy Serkis played him as well, and they had a giant speaker hooked up to his mic that shifted his pitch a few octaves down, so while they were filming he was there grunting and gorilla-screaming at the appropriate times.  I don't recall if any of that was used in post, however (I doubt it).

Comment: Does Darth Vader's breathing count, or did he have too many English lines as well?

Comment: Are you suggesting that Peter Mayhew and Kenny Baker did *not* make the sounds of their characters? If so, you should probably mention who/what *does* make the sounds, since you are implying that Peter Mayhew and Kenny Baker didn't make the sounds for their characters.

Comment: What about Vin Diesel as Groot in Guardians of the Galaxy? Frankly I think the question would be more interesting if you excluded CGI.

Comment: @TylerH done. see links in the new edit.

Answer (score 26):

[Andy Serkis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Serkis) was the CGI actor for Gollum, and provided the voice as well.

> His work on The Lord of the Rings started a debate on the legitimacy of CGI-assisted acting. Some critics felt Serkis should have been nominated for the Academy Award for Best Supporting Actor, since **his voice, body language, and facial expressions were used**. There is the argument that his CGI actions were partially, or in some cases fully, animated without his movements, but the same is true for actors in a traditional film with CGI. Serkis does appear briefly as Sméagol before he transforms into Gollum, and the CGI Gollum's facial characteristics are fundamentally based on Serkis' own.

He also did the motion capture and some of the vocalizations of Caesar in the rebooted *Planet of the Apes* series.

And all the Navi in *Avatar* were voiced by the actors themselves;  most have few if any English lines.

Comment: "I'm asking about creatures/characters __who don't have a lot of (english) lines,__ like Chewie. We're talking grunting, roaring, hissing, or strange, exotic languages like wookiee roars (so Jar Jar, Groot, and Unkar Plutt don't count)." I'll try to clarify

Comment: @RedCaio - He's named after the sound he makes more often than he speaks - *GOLLUM!*

Comment: Caesar counts. Gollum has loads of lines so it's not really what I'm going for. +1 for including the Caesar part though. :)

Comment: I always had a hard time understanding what Gollum was saying with such a stylized accent. It's almost not English. Maybe you should give him a half a point.

Answer (score 2):

[James Spader](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2395427/?ref_=nv_sr_1) did both the motion capture and the voice for Ultron in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

See this [small clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLvKRIrTvRA).

Comment: Ultron exclusively spoke English - this does not answer the question.

Comment: Fair point - I didn't account for that.